# Can not Access the disposed object( Xamarin forms (5.0)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am getting below error, When i try to Assign the Appshell to MainPage

System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ShellFlyoutRenderer'.'

Code:

Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();

Initially, I had SpleshScreen as MainPage, Then I redirected to Google OAuth to get Auth token.

Once I get the Token, I try to Assign AppShell to the main page but get the Error.

Answer (score 0):

**FIX 1:**
Perhaps you've already created an AppShell. If so, remove the code or xaml that created it the first time. Two places to look:

1. In code. Is there anywhere else that already says `new AppShell();`? If so, remove that (or comment it out).
2. In App.xaml. Does it look something like this:

```xml
<Application ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        ...
    </Application.Resources>

    <!-- This section creates an app Shell -->
    <Shell ...>
        ...
    </Shell>
</Application>
```

If so, the entire `<Shell> ... </Shell>` needs to be in its own xaml file, `AppShell.xaml`.

---

**FIX #2:**

Perhaps you create AppShell at a place in code where Xamarin is not ready to make a UI change. Wrap it in BeginInvoke...:

```cs
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
});
```

Comment: We have 3 shell file created that always start from one class, no other class trying to attach the shell, we are assigning the new shell inside the main threads as you have mentioned above. 

we are having three methods like below:
public void startMainShell(){
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
});

Comment: And you are sure there is no mention of `<Shell ...` anywhere in any XAML?  First place to check is App.xaml.

Comment: yes,  we do not have any shell tag in any other file.

Comment: but every page we have 
 <Shell.TitleView>
        <ContentView Padding="0">
            <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                FontSize="16" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        </ContentView>
    </Shell.TitleView>

will this cause issue? I tried removing it then also the same issue.

Comment: That should be okay. I'm out of ideas. You could make a public github repo, as simple as possible to run and show the issue, and create an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues