# android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-shell

Every time I launch my Xamarin form app, it gives me the following exception and crashes.
. It keeps crashing even after restarting the app. I had to uninstall and reinstall the app.

After that, the application works fine without any code changes, but once this exception occurs, I have to reinstall it.

7-29 22:34:26.291  4590  4590 I MonoDroid: UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
07-29 22:34:26.295  4590  4590 I MonoDroid: Android.Runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: Exception of type 'Android.Runtime.JavaProxyThrowable' was thrown.
07-29 22:34:26.296  4590  4590 I MonoDroid:   --- End of managed Android.Runtime.JavaProxyThrowable stack trace ---
07-29 22:34:26.296  4590  4590 I MonoDroid: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
07-29 22:34:26.296  4590  4590 I MonoDroid: Object name: 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ShellFlyoutRenderer'.
07-29 22:34:26.296  4590  4590 I MonoDroid:   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.AssertSelf (Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self) [0x00029] in :0
07-29 22:34:26.296  4590  4590 I MonoDroid:   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualBooleanMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00000] in :0
07-29 22:34:26.296  4590  4590 I MonoDroid:   at Android.Views.View.Post (Java.Lang.IRunnable action) [0x00036] in <1db5751744294c2d9a12968f7500aa0a>:0
07-29 22:34:26.296  4590  4590 I MonoDroid:   at Android.Views.View.Post (System.Action action) [0x00008] in <1db5751744294c2d9a12968f7500aa0a>:0
07-29 22:34:26.296  4590  4590 I MonoDroid:   at Xam.Shell.Badge.Droid.Renderers.BadgeShellItemRenderer.b__7_0 () [0x0000b] in <03ed10528a1e495baf36a579de381653>:0
07-29 22:34:26.296  4590  4590 I MonoDroid:   at Xamarin.Forms.Device+<>c__DisplayClass42_0`1[T].b__0 () [0x00000] in <62e3629c74b84e3d834046331d2bb5f8>:0
07-29 22:34:26.296  4590  4590 I MonoDroid: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Environment :
Xamarin form:5.0.0.2401
target Os: android 8.1
editor: vs studio 2022 professional

Comment: At first, you can try to upgrade or downgrade the xamarin.forms package version. And then, there was a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72344521/can-not-access-the-disposed-object-xamarin-forms-5-0) and you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

Run your app on windows machine the error will be clear and can catch it easily, after that go back to android